# Como verificar o Width do Body toda vez que mudar de Tamanho em Jquery

Tags: jquery

Estava verificando o tamanho do `body` pelo `$(window).resize` mas percebo que ao iniciar a página inicialmente o tamanho ta certo mas não aplica às `classes`. Segue o Código:

```js
jQuery.noConflict()(function($) {
  "use strict";

  $(document).ready(function() { // Inicializar app quando o documento esta pronto
    $(window).on('load', function() {
      $('.preloader').delay(350).fadeOut(); // Page Preloading
      $('body').hide().delay(350).show(); // Force Chrome to repaint fonts
      checkSize();
      $(window).resize(checkSize);
    });
  });

  function checkSize() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width >= 320 || width <= 480) {
      $('.teste').addClass('celular').removeClass('desktop phablet').html('Celular: '+width);
    } else if (width >= 481 || width <= 767) {
      $('.teste').addClass('phablet').removeClass('desktop celular').html('Phablet: '+width);
    } else {
      $('.teste').addClass('desktop').removeClass('celular phablet').html('Desktop: '+width);
    }
  }

}(jQuery)); // Passar em (jQuery):
```

```css
#body {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="body">
  <div class="teste"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na verificação de tamanho você usou o operador OU, desta forma ele acaba sempre entrando no primeiro if, afinal a página sempre é maior que 320 ou menor que 480

```
if (width >= 320 || width <= 480)
```

O correto seria usar o operador AND

```
if (width >= 320 && width <= 480) {
    //se for maior ou igual que 320 E menor ou igual a 480
} else if (width >= 481 && width <= 767) {
    //se for maior ou igual a 481 E menor ou igual a 767
} else {
    //em qualquer outro caso
}
```